# Can I have more than 5000 options for a custom field?

Tags: custom-fields, fieldoptions

Running Drupal 7.94/CiviCRM 5.57

I've created a custom field for an activity that contains 5,000 choices. Seems to work fine on the CiviCRM Admin side, but when I add that same field to a Webform I get this error:

"PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'extra' at row..."

What would be an effective manner to correct this?

Comment: 5000 choices!  Just wondering whether there is a better way to structure that.  What's the goal?

Comment: Is this of type multi-select or checkbox?

Comment: Type is Autocomplete-Select.

The field collects which law a contact is suspected of being arrested for.  The dataset contains 5600 total laws. I can likely trim that down to 2600 but I still get the same error.

Comment: we have approached this previously by creating a specific table, and folk choose from that, and then (from memory) the form pushes that value in to a simple txt field in civi